# How to prevent Play from running main methods of sub projects

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.1

So I have a directory structure as such

```
EntireProject/
    -project/
    -mainProject/
    -subProject/
    -miscDir/
```

Here's my Build.scala file

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "SampleProject"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm
  )

  val subProject = Project("sub-project",file("subProject"))


  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("mainProject"))
    .dependsOn(subProject)

}
```

When i run "play run", play runs the App object in the subproject as well.  So how do I prevent the subProjects from being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's one or all of three things.  One, it (probably) should be

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("mainProject"))
.dependsOn(subProject).aggregate(subProject)
```

Two, and this is most likely the problem, that subproject should really be a play.Project.  Play projects are extensions of sbt projects, and play is really just an alias for sbt which adds the play functionality.  So something like:

```
lazy val subProject = play.Project(appName + "subproject", 
    appVersion, appDependencies, path=file("subProject").settings(

)
```

Three, double check the correct project is selected as the main project by opening the play console (type play at command line).  Then from inside the play console, do what

When you have a sub-project enabled in your build, you can focus on this project and compile, test or run it individually. Just use the projects command in the Play console prompt to display all projects:

```
[my-first-application] $ projects
[info] In file:/Volumes/Data/gbo/myFirstApp/
[info]   * my-first-application
[info]     my-library
```

and then enter `project SampleProject` to select the correct one if it is not selected.

[EDIT:] Also, as this [document](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects) indicates,

> The default project is the one whose variable name comes first alphabetically. You may make your main project by making its variable name aaaMain.

Well, naming it aaaMain is one way.  But just call your main project appName, and then call all your subprojects appName+"-subname".

Comment: I don't understand why the subproject should be a play project too. This exemple is also shawn in the play documentation but I do not agree. If you build a library, you don't need for this library the whole SBT settings added to the Play Project

Comment: Yes, I've had issues with that doc a lot recently.  I think it was only published a couple months ago.  Anyway, with the simplest project matching the OPs structure, when I do it as you describe, with the subproject as a normal SBT project, play indeed tries to find a main method to run in the subproject, just as plain SBT would.   I am very interested in your thoughts on this though.

Comment: I checked the projects in the console and apparently my subProject was selected.  I also changed the subProject to play.Project.  So after selecting the main project and changing the subProject to a Play project its not executing the subProject as main anymore.

Comment: Actually I may end up having X webapps using a couple of common code (I also split in many subprojects: core, test, domain, business, search, messaging...). These X webapps will have the same release lifecycle so it makes sens to use the same version for all of them, like we usually do in a Maven multimodule build

Comment: Great, glad to hear that worked.  @Sebastien, that sounds a lot better, I wonder how you get around the main execution, even of the subprojects.  Maybe it's an issue in the play version I'm using.

Comment: @ZakPatterson, do you know how to ensure that the mainProject is always the main? I find that play now needs me to select the main project every time I restart it.